# Change line behavior of a combined chart in SAPUI5 VizFrame

Tags: sapui5

I am using a combined chart (Stacked Column + Line) for my application. Is it possible to change the line plotting?. (somewhat like shown in RED in the image). If yes then how is it possible?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you already know the [VIZ documentation](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/vizdocs/index.html) where you can find all possible properties of VizFrame. As far as I know there currently is no way to get the behavior you're asking for except for writing your own lineRenderer (vizProperties.plotArea.lineRenderer). There is one alternative line plotting mode available which is smoothening it but I'm sure thats not what you want.

However you could use a second series of column chart instead. Just use a standard column chart and add two data series instead of one. I think this would show the exact information you're trying to get with the current diagram just no connection between them.